# Prove that $E+BA$ is invertible if $(E + AB)^{-1}$ exist.

Tags: linear-algebra

For matrix:
$$
E+AB, ∃ (E+AB)^{-1}
$$
E-identity matrix.

Proof that:
$$
∃(E+BA)^{-1}
$$
I know that i should prove this equation: $(E-BCA)(E+BA)=E$, $C = (E+AB)^{-1}$

Can't understand how I should arrive for this equation, and how proof that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not understandable. Where is the matrix $C$ coming from? You say "I know that i should prove this equation with $C$". Why do you know that?

Comment: $C = (E + AB)^{-1}$ Sorry forgot hint this. Will edit now. Got this from answers from problems book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

1. The only way $I+BA$ is not invertible is if there is a nonzero $x$ such that the equation $BA(x)=-x$ holds. Make sure you see why. So suppose that $I+BA$ is not invertible and there exists such an $x$.
2. But then set $y=A(x)$, where $x$ is as in 1. above. Then $y$ is nonzero [why] and the equation $BA(x)=-x$ gives the string of equations $AB(y)=AB(A(x))$ $=A(BA(x))$ $=A(-x)=-y$. So then in particular $BA(x)=-x$ $\implies AB(y)=-y$.
3. But then letting $y$ be as in 2., the equation $(I +AB)y = 0$ holds. So $I +AB$ cannot be invertible after all...

Comment: Thanks, even not thought about this way.